# Symfony - easyadmin 4 filetype constraint on ImageField

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

How can I limit the `ImageField` to only accept png and jpg?

This is my code, but the issue is that i can upload pdf or .exe as well.

I cannot find a way to add a constraint here.

```php
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('entryTitle'),
            TextEditorField::new('entryText'),
            AssociationField::new('entryCategory'),
            ImageField::new('mainImage')
                ->setBasePath('uploads/images/Blog')
                ->setUploadDir('public/uploads/images/Blog')
                ->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[randomhash].[extension]')
                ->setHelp('Only .png and .jpg')
        ];
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it's natively possible for the moment, but you can create your own `Constraints` to limit image types. Check this issue it will give you a workaround https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/5227.

Comment: Provided example in the @Lounis link is working on EA4 and S5.4 too.

Answer (score 2):

You should just add an `@Assert\File` on your property.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize="5M",
 *     maxSizeMessage="File exceed limit of: {{limit}}.",
 *     mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "File must be a JPG or PNG."
 * )
 */
private ?File $imageFile = null;
```

Or if you really want to set it up manually you could use `setFormTypeOption`:

```
ImageField::new('mainImage')
    ->setBasePath('uploads/images/Blog')
    ->setUploadDir('public/uploads/images/Blog')
    ->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[randomhash].[extension]')
    ->setHelp('Only .png and .jpg')
    ->setFormTypeOption('constraints', [
        new File([
            'maxSize' => '5M',
            'mimeTypes' => [
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/png',
            ],
            'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid image. '
        ])
    ]);
```

Comment: now the issue is that i got "The file could not be found."wheni add the constraint. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your property and form configuration, maybe post another question or update it

Comment: answer of @Lounis is the right for the moment. apparently easyadmin does not have that for the moment

Comment: I have multiple fields with file constraints in my forms, but I did create my own ImageField to use with vich and `@Assert\File` works fine.